# Equivalent of GDB 'start' in JDB?

Tags: java, gdb, jdb

I'm a bit confused by JDB. Being fairly good at using GDB, I'm aware of the various simple commands used to control the execution, i.e. start, run, cont, step, stepi, break, etc. but there are a number of (in my opinion) unusual differences.

If I wish to start an application (as opposed to *running* it, so I can step it from the start), instinctively, I type `jdb MyApp` and then `start`. I get an unrecognized command error. Reading the JDB help gives me no indication at all of a start command or its equivalent. So, I try `step` - that doesn't work either; I am told that I need to start the Java VM with the `run` command!

Clearly, it must be possible, because there is a `step` command explained in the help. So, I figure that maybe I can type `run` and very quickly press `ctrl+c` to interrupt it as, in GDB, this stops the execution. Instead, it just quits JDB.

I've tried googling this, to no avail. I hope I'm not being totally blind stupid!

Rant over: how on earth do you just start running a java application in JDB so that you can step it, from the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the VM hasn't launched, which is why you can't step into the first line. The solution is to start JDB with "-launch" as a command line argument. From there you can type "step" or "cont" to start debugging from the start.

The best bit is it only takes a second and doesn't require installing an IDE :-)

Answer (score 6):

I have just started to use `JDB` as a debugger. There are good instructions that can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdb.html). To answer some of your questions:

1. To start `jdb`, at the command prompt, type `jdb <name of main class>`
2. To start the program, type `run`
3. To set a breakpoint, type: `stop at <class>:<line no.>`
4. To step, type `cont`

As I said, I have just started to use `jdb` just now. There are, I am sure, better ways to do the above and I will post here should I get to know more myself.

HTH.

Comment: on the CTRL-C: it looks to me like after starting the application with `run`, input to jdb is still active, i.e. just pressing enter should give a new jdb prompt and one can use the `suspend` command to suspend all threads

Answer (score 0):

I am reading this material as a never-ever user of Java, but a fairly accomplished user of gdb for c.  I have had many, many occasions to need to step into the first executable line of source - so commonly that I almost always use the following sequence to start gdb.

Before issuing the "run" command, set a breakpoint at "main".  Then "run" will load the program, but will break before executing the first step.

This may be totally inapplicable for Java, but I thought I would make the suggestion.

Answer (score -4):

I suggest you use an IDE to run the debugger. In the IDE you can start in debug by clicking the button next to run, add breakpoints by clicking on a line and view the state of threads and variables graphically. (even change them)

Comment: I'm not a fan of IDEs in my line of programming; surely if an IDE can do what I require, then `jdb` can, since the IDE is likely to be a front end to it?

Comment: Surely it can, but why make things far more complicated than they need to be. Shouldn't it be about making the best use of the tools available to get the job done? What is your line of programming out of interest?

Comment: Well most of my programming is on the subject of back-ends or purely number-crunching. IDEs annoy me really. I've used `GDB` on the command-line for a long time and it's fantastic; I have no desire to use an IDE whatsoever. To me, it just adds bulk to the writing process and doesn't make me feel like I've achieved much. So, in light of that, do you know the answer to my original question please?

Comment: I developed for many years using vi and thought IDEs where for the 'soft' developers. Thats was 10 years ago. IDEs have improved alot since then and I think once you learn to use IDEs you will wonder how much time you wasted doing things the hard way. So I think the best thing I can do for you is to rethink your approach. BTW: I only develop large, performance critical server side systems.

Comment: another case for using jdb vs. an IDE is when the development machine (e.g. Desktop) is not the execution machine (e.g. server) and the IDE isn't installed on the execution machine

Comment: @AndreHolzner You can do remote debugging of a server side application without installing additional software. You just need to add command line arguments to start in debug mode and it can accept remote debugging IDEs.